# Need 3D GIS/mapping framework similar to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, geography

I need to develop a 3D mapping/visualisation system that tightly integrates with Google Maps-like functionality. I need the ability to change the angle of view to the ground (instead of the fixed perpendicular on Google Maps) and then render content 'above ground' (e.g. to show an aircraft or some other content) actually floating above the ground at a given elevation and (possibly in 3D, it might just be 2D labels). Linked in with this is the need for path guidance, searching for addresses, businesses and your normal map functions.

Google Earth was our first thought but the API has been deprecated and Google Maps V3 doesn't seem to offer anything like this. Bing Maps 3D has also been abandoned. http://www.webglearth.org/ provides an API but only perpendicular view.

What frameworks exist for this kind of thing? Is ArcGIS the only thing out there? Doesn't have to be web based, but needs to be able to run on Windows.

Note: I'm aware a couple of older questions about this given the changes in available products, thought best to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [World Wind](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/). There is also the [Virtual Terrain Project](http://vterrain.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an free and open-source JavaScript platform, I recommend the [TerriaJS](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs) with Leaflet and Cesium (3D library).

I have come across many light-weight, responsive 3D globes with features such as compare, time-aware animations built using this platform.

You can see it in action at [nationalmap.gov.au](https://www.nationalmap.gov.au/)